# Java code to read website contents

Tags: java, web-crawler

Is there any way in Java to read the contents of a webpage?

Webpage is not a simple HTML page, it contains an ajax call, image, PDF and Flash.
I need to read / download all the contents of the page (after the ajax call is executed).

Please suggest me any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose various html parser present.you can use one of them

http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

http://jsoup.org/

http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

these solution extracts your html tags included images. for css extraction you can use css parser.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a crawler and processing tools.

There are many  [open source crawlers](http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers) listed. You can use it with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), a search server